# Skype opening links in wrong browser

Tags: skype

I have Google Chrome set as my default browser in 17.10 using the settings app and everything seems to behave properly except Skype, which insists on opening every clicked link in Firefox.

xdg-mime shows Chrome, 
/etc/alternatives shows Chrome, 
mimeapps.list shows Chrome.

Is there anywhere else I can check?

Answer (score 13):

I uninstalled the version that came from the "Ubuntu Software" app and downloaded the .deb directly from skype.com. Although it's the same version number, this does not have the link problem.

Comment: I wish snap version. I just don't know how to reconfigure it.

Comment: This one works!

Answer (score 4):

It's due to Skype being installed as a Snap package, I assume with wrong configs at the snap sandbox level.

The easiest solution is just to install the .deb installer file from Skype directly.

Comment: I wish snap version. I need help with snap sandbox config.